# Is it possible to modify a variable of the parent in a subshell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Here is an example:

```
bash-4.2$ export i=0
bash-4.2$ while :; do let i=i+1; done &
[1] 29668
bash-4.2$ echo $i
0
bash-4.2$ kill %1
bash-4.2$ exit
```

Here, the job I started keeps increasing `$i` but only as a local variable. I know in bash there is no such a thing as pointers or references, so my question is how to do it?

If it's possible somehow, then it would mean it's possible to access and write one variable in more than one threads at the same time, which is what I want to achieve. Is there a way to prevent memory reading/writing problems with something like critical sections (in shell/bash)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash 4 supports [coprocesses](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#SEC23) which is simply a behind-the-scenes method of using a two-way pipe.

Answer (score 1):

Bash doesn't have threads, and processes don't share memory.  And subshells are still different processes - they inherit their state from their parent, but they have no shared data with them.

The parent can read output from a subshell or other process and then change its own state, but there's no way for the child to do so directly.

Comment: As stated [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists), if I end a command with & sign it executes the command in a subshell asynchronously. I asked whether I can make a global variable that both the parent and the children can write, but it seems it's only possible through pipes and additional code (coproc simpifies it). Btw when I said thread I meant that every process has threads it's not necessity to be part of the same process. Thanks for the info though.

Comment: Every process on Linux has at least one thread, including processes running the bash interpreter.  That doesn't change the fact that bash has no way to spawn multiple threads.  The only form of multiprocessing available with bash is processes.

Comment: And you're right about subshells - any time the shell forks off a child that continues from the same starting execution context, it's a subshell.  But it's still also a subprocess, and the same rules apply:  no way to mod the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, these are not threads, they are processes.  There is no straightforward way of a child altering the variables of a parent process (the only way I know of is to attach a C program as a debugger).

Better to use a pipe, possibly a named pipe, to pass data back to the caller.